# How to test android app on all screen sizes

Tags: android, testing, genymotion, screen-size

I've created my app but I decided to **test** it on **all screens** to be **adaptive**. Maybe **testing** it in
`MDPI(160dpi), HDPI(240dpi), XHDPI(320dpi), XXHDPI(480dpi) and XXXHDPI(640dpi)` which corresponds to all screen sizes. However I tested my app on two devices support `320dpi`. I thought that I get the same result but **it don't**. so don't know how to test my app on all screens. I'm confused.

I used **Genymotion** for emulators:
one with 720 * 1280 `320dpi`
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvY36.png)
and other with 1200 * 1920 `320dpi`[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbjXd.png)

Please help me with that or if there's another way to do it let me know.
thanks in advance

Comment: One way: Use the pop-up feature on your phone to open the app in the pop-up and change its size then, the second way change the device preview inside the android studio for the layout you want to test to see how it would render.

Comment: @Haris yea i can use android preview but how to customize a specific design for larger screen and another for smaller one like changing in text views size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Bunch of explanation about why this is happening, I put my suggestions in the last section)*

*DPI* isn't the same as *size*, it's just about how many pixels are packed into a certain area. The higher the DPI, the more pixels there are, meaning they're a lot smaller. So you can get fine detail, but it also means you need more of them to cover a physical distance or area on the screen.

Which is why Android uses `dp` instead of raw pixel sizes most of the time - the standard minimum touch-target size is *48dp*, but how many actual *pixels* that is depends on the pixel density of the display. [For *mdpi* displays it'll actually be 48 pixels, for *xxxhdpi* it'll be **4x** that amount](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

It also means if you're doing your design work in `dp`, the pixel density of the screen doesn't matter - elements with a fixed size will always be broadly the same size on every screen (the *mdpi* etc buckets are like a "close enough" grouping, the devices in each group won't all have *exactly* the same DPI) because it's getting translated to the equivalent number of actual pixels. What testing does help with is checking your drawable assets look ok on different screen densities

---

So you have two devices with the *same DPI* right?

- **720 x 1280**
- **1200 x 1920**

Because they're the same DPI, those dimensions are converted to *dp* by the same factor. Let's work it out to be precise (but the exact numbers aren't important): *320 DPI* is *xhdpi* according to that link up there, so *1dp = 2px*. Let's convert those screen sizes to *dp*

- **360dp x 640dp**
- **600dp x 960dp**

It's the same situation but hopefully having those sizes expressed in *dp* helps you see the problem - when you're designing a layout, you're working with *dp*, right? The available space you have to work with is defined in *dp*, and one of those has a whole lot more space than the other! Putting a *300 dp*-wide `TextView` in the layout would almost fill the first one horizontally, but it would only cover half of the second. That's gonna look pretty different!

This is why phones and tablets look so different - even if you have a relatively new phone, and an old Nexus 7 with a much lower resolution, the Nexus 7's screen is going to feel "bigger" and more "spacious". It's a physically larger device, so even though it's low-res, it's also low-density which means those pixels are spread across a larger area. Lower DPI means those pixels translate into more inches. And in the *density-independent pixel (dp)* system, that means you get way more *dp* to work with, more space for your layout. Which is what you want on a tablet, you don't want it to look and feel like a massive phone!

---

That's *why* it's different - basically one of your devices has more space to work with than the other, because it has more pixels, and the same DPI so those pixels aren't just used for finer detail.

As for testing, you need to look at different screen sizes - which is dependent on the resolution **and** the DPI. Basically `pixels / DPI = size` in inches. Do that for your two *320 DPI* examples and you'll see one is a fair bit larger, physically, while having the same density

Probably the easiest way to do this, really, is to look at your layout in the design view, and change the `Preview Device` setting at the top. Some of the *Phone* devices are more "spacious" than others, newer ones are taller, so go through them and see how your layout changes. Try a *Tablet* one and see what a *lot* of extra space does. And if you go down to the `Generic Phones and Tablets` section at the bottom, there are a bunch of reference devices in there, some of which will be very cramped!

Once you've found a few useful ones, you can set up your emulator / virtual devices with each of their screen resolution / density combinations. I don't know about Genymotion, but the built-in AVD manager gives you a lot of those device definitions as templates when you create a new virtual device. You should at least be able to enter those settings yourself

Also when you publish an app on the Play Store, they'll automatically run it on a bunch of reference devices and give you access to a bunch of screenshots, so you can see if there are any problems with certain screen sizes and fix them before you launch

Comment: I really appreciate that awesome explanation, now I understood how that happened and yea there's lots of devices cramped and spacious in device preview. but how that can help me there's just **icons** drawable and **text views** how I can make text views' **size** be **responsive** in all screens and change? Is there's a way so I can get **inches** and use it to change **"dimens"** file so I can solve sizes for icons and text views or any other way in resources or programmatically!@cactustictacs

Comment: @AhmedSaad the baseline density is *mdpi*, which is *160 DPI*. At that density, 1 *pixel* = 1 *dp* - and that's how *dp* is defined. So basically, *160 dp* is *1 inch* on every screen, or thereabouts. But the whole point of *dp* is that whatever the screen density, your stuff will always be *the same size* in real, hold-a-ruler-against-the-screen terms. But because *screens* are different real-world sizes, you have to design different, separate layouts that rely on different amounts of space, or create a responsive layout that allows its Views to resize and move appropriately

Comment: That's a pretty complex topic and not one that I'm an expert in either, so all I can do is point you at a few resources: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support#sizes https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: Seems that i got a solution, i just created my layout once and created dimen file contains dp values for textSize and drawble width and height and i am creating just about 3 or 4 dimen files, one for small screen, one for medium, one for large and one for tablet. Fortunately its worked. So i used your calculations to get dp for each device and i tried multiple screen previews so its really helps although their screen specs is not accurate, so values  adaptive  through the smallest width qualifier. And finally its worked!!

Comment: @AhmedSaad, nice, great job! It's a lot of work huh, but it's nice when you get something you're happy with that looks decent on everything. But if you're actually resizing text and images to fit a certain amount of space (instead of using a fixed *sp* or *dp* size and calling it a day) then take a look at *autosizing `TextView`s* (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) and *`ratio`* constraints (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#ratio) - just for the future, you already got something working!

Comment: It seems attractive topic. Yea, this is what exactly I want. Maybe I implement it in the next updates. Thank you again @cactustictacs